# std::variant внутрянняя цикличность(JSON)

Tags: c++, c++17

Захотелось мне парсер сделать для JSON.

```
using JsonData = std::variant<vector<JsonData>, std::unordered_map<string, JsonData>, double, bool, string>;
```

Но так он не ест.

Как можно заставить его такое съесть? Только самому юнион небезопасный писать?

Comment: Если места не жалко - можно взять все готовое https://github.com/nlohmann/json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать вот так:

```
struct JsonData
{
    using data_t = std::variant<vector<JsonData>, std::unordered_map<string, JsonData>, double, bool, string>;
    data_t data;
};
```

(`using` - просто для удобства, можно обойтись без него.)